# Giving wrapped flexbox items vertical spacing

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've recently been playing with Flexbox for the first time and, in general, it's absolutely amazing. I've encountered an issue recently however, where I cannot seem to give flex items that are wrapping any vertical spacing.

I've tried using:

```
align-content: space-between;
```

but this doesn't seem to do anything. From the reading I've done, this would only seem to work if my flex container is taller than the elements contained within (is this right?) If so, then would I not have to set a height for my flex-container, which would seem to defeat the purpose of using flexbox?

The only way I can think of to make this work would be to give bottom margin to the elements within, but again this seems to defeat the purpose.

Hopefully I'm missing something fairly obvious - here's a link to a codepen: http://codepen.io/lordchancellor/pen/pgMEPz

Also, here's my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="col-sm-12">
     <h1>Flexbox Wrapping</h1>

     <div class="flexContainer">
       <div class="flexLabel">This is a flex label</div>
                    
       <a class="btn btn-primary">Button 1</a>
       <a class="btn btn-warning">Button 2</a>
       <a class="btn btn-success">Button 3</a>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```css
.flexContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: space-between;
  justify-content: center;
}
.flexContainer .flexLabel {
  flex-basis: 150px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

EDIT - Just going to add a little more detail here, as I'm not sure I'm putting it across well enough.

In my larger project, I have some block level elements that are arranged in a row using flexbox. However, there needs to be some responsiveness as the user may reduce the screen width. At this point, I want my elements to begin to stack (hence the wrap). However, as the elements begin to stack, they are all touching vertically, where I want there to be spacing.

It's beginning to look like top and bottom margins may be the only way to resolve this - however I was wondering if there was a flexbox-centric way to achieve this.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

If you force wrapping by applying a width you can then use margins as you normally would without setting a height.

```css
.flexContainer {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  background: pink;
  width: 150px;
}
.flexContainer > * {
  margin: 1em 0;
}
.flexContainer .flexLabel {
  flex-basis: 150px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <h1>Flexbox Wrapping</h1>

    <div class="flexContainer">

      <div class="flexLabel">This is a flex label</div>

      <a class="btn btn-primary">Button 1</a>
      <a class="btn btn-warning">Button 2</a>
      <a class="btn btn-success">Button 3</a>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The no wrap seems to be a typo though because it's overwritten two lines later with `flex-wrap: wrap;`

Comment: Yes you're absolutely right, the nowrap was an idiotic typo, as I lifted this code snippet from my larger project!

Comment: The question has been edited now but the fact remains is the the items are not wrapping because the parent is wide enough to accommodate them.

Comment: So I take from this that the best solution is actually to pop some margin on the elements? That's fine - though I had thought that flexbox was supposed to eliminate the need to use margins to space out your elements. Thanks for your input @Paulie_D.

Comment: It will space elements across a known height but not if you don't set one, how could it?

Comment: I for one was hoping for something similar to `padding-top` as percentage of regular divs, that actually relates to width so it's useful in allowing uniform space around the elements.
As it is now, horizontal distances are variable while vertical ones are set to fixed values, which doesn't always look nice. I'm wondering if there may be some hack around this.

Comment: This is a poor implementation though, there needs to be wrapSpacing property to solve this.

Comment: @lordchancellor You probably already know this, but for those who don't, `column-gap` and `row-gap` are what to use to set vertical and horizontal gutters for flexbox displays. (I don't know how well they were supported in 2016.) You can also use `gap` to set both at once if they are the same.

Comment: @BobRodes `gap` doesn't seem to work with wrapping. If I have a row flexbox with a `gap` of `1%` set to `wrap` and it wraps onto the next line, there is space between items in one row, but no space between "rows" (the one wrapped row that spans multiple visual rows)

Comment: @AdamWójcik Hmm. I'll take your word for it, and good thing to know. :)

Answer (score 85):

row-gap would solve your problem

```
.flexbox {
    display: flex;
    column-gap: 10px;
    row-gap: 10px
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Not supported by IE11, but otherwise solid support.

Comment: this is actually the thing I was looking for 

Comment: this is the simplest and the most accurate answer imo, should be accepted.

Comment: just `gap` would work as well.

Answer (score 75):

I had a similar issue and I used the following *hack* to solve the issue.

```
    /* add a negative top-margin to the flex container */
.flexContainer {
        /* ... your existing flex container styles here */
    margin: -10px 0 0 0;
} 
    /* add a corresponding positive top margin to all flex items (all direct children of the flex container) */
.flexContainer > * {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

For the top row of flex items the negative and positive margins cancel out, for the subsequent rows it adds the margin between the rows (in this case `10px` between rows).

*It's less than elegant but it gets the job done.*

Comment: Why are negative margins considered a hack?

Comment: In this case, because this is not margin's desired use to fix flexbox gaps and margin is used in cooperation with another margin in another object to affect the appearance of the other object. So, this makes it less elegant because it can easily be considered bad practice for spaghetti logic (change object A to fix object B + unorthodox use of margin to fix flexbox). I think that the solution though is nice, apart from the hacky aspect of it which is not for OP to blame but CSS & browsers themselves for not having a clean way to solve this.

Comment: Apparently that's the way to do it, at least according to Mozilla :)
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Mastering_Wrapping_of_Flex_Items#creating_gutters_between_items

Answer (score 7):

It's because you don't have a height on your flex content for it to calculate the space-between so at the moment, the flex container is as small as possible.  Add a height and it should work.

Comment: Maybe what you're looking for is `flex-direction: column`?  Not sure.

Comment: A little late to the party but for those searching... Additionally to this, you could a bottom margin to each element

Answer (score 3):

Another hacky solution is to give the item a bottom border:

```css
border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
```

Comment: Useful for cases when the height is 100%

Comment: Why not use a transparent border while you're at it? Makes this just a little less hacky.

Comment: What is the advantage to using border over margin?